# Importing typeface through CSS

Tags: css, font-face, typeface, font-family

I'm attempting to import a custom font using the CSS `@font-face`. So far, it's been unsuccessful. I have looked for various options but all have not worked. Below is what I have tried.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTSt";
    src: url({{ 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md.otf' | asset_url}});
}
```

The brackets in the src url is from Shopify. It links to the following URL /t/3/assets/style-light.css?3035

Here's the corresponding CSS

```
#productHeader h1 {font-family:'HelveticaNeueLTStd', serif;font-size:22px;margin:0px 0 5px 0;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:.4px;line-height:28px;}
#subproductVendor{font-family:'HelveticaNeueLTStd', serif;color:#333;font-size:14px;font-weight:600;text-transform:lowercase;}
#productVendor {font-family:'HelveticaNeueLTStd', serif;color:#333;font-size:22px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:500;}
```

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong, because most tutorials on this subject provide such information. Any thoughts on how I could get this to work?

Comment: the way you are declaring the font face is correct, my guess is something is not right with the shipify url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'EmmysFont';
    src: url('font/emmys__-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/emmys__-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/emmys__-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/emmys__-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/emmys__-webfont.svg#emmysfontregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This code, and also make sure you've got all the files right - FontSquirrel does the trick!

Comment: What if I only have a .otf of the typeface?

Comment: Then you head over to FontSquirrel! http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator